# Python import error from xx.xx import * : no module named

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my file structure:

```
-test

--m1

---t.py

--m2

---__init__.py

---utils.py
```

t.py:

```
from m2.utils import *
print foo()
```

utils.py:

```
def foo():
  return 5
```

__init__.py is empty

It works in my local environment (macOS Sierra python 2.7.10):

```
Shangtong@Shangtong:~/GitHub/PaperReplication/test$ python m1/t.py
5
Shangtong@Shangtong:~/GitHub/PaperReplication/test$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/Users/Shangtong/DevelopmentKits/libsvm-3.20/python
```

However it doesn't work in my server (Python 2.7.8):

```
[shangton@jasper test]$ python m1/t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m1/t.py", line 1, in <module>
    from m2.utils import *
ImportError: No module named m2.utils
[shangton@jasper test]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 shangton shangton 4096 Jan 28 09:10 .
drwx------ 4 shangton shangton 4096 Jan 28 10:09 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 shangton shangton 4096 Jan 28 09:12 m1
drwxrwxr-x 2 shangton shangton 4096 Jan 28 10:09 m2
[shangton@jasper test]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/global/software/python/Python-2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/global/software/python/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:~/PaperReplication/:~/test/m2:~/test
```

Comment: If you had a `m1/__init__.py`, you could run `python -m m1.t`

Comment: ...or if you set `PYTHONPATH=$PWD`, then this should work immediately as you intend.

Comment: `~` isn't guaranteed to expand -- use `$HOME`, not `~`, when setting environment variables. Python *may* do it manually -- there's a library function for the purpose -- but many programs won't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It works! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're demonstrating that your PYTHONPATH contains:

```
~/test/m2:~/test
```

However, `~` is not actually a valid PATH component! It's a hint *to your shell* to replace that character with your home directory (when unquoted, in the first position in a word, and otherwise where other conditions are met) -- but Python is not your shell, and if your shell didn't honor that hint when you were setting the environment variable (perhaps because, being in the middle of a string, it wasn't in leading position), it won't be honored later unless Python explicitly calls `os.path.expanduser()`.

When setting an environment variable, use `$HOME`:

```
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/test
```

Comment: It works.Thanks! Could you please explain one more thing: why does it work in my local environment?

Comment: In your local environment, there's no `~` in your PYTHONPATH.